# ESLINT does not get syntax error from HML tag

Tags: reactjs, eslint, create-react-app

I'm doing some tests here with ESLINT and I noticed that it doesn't get an error when it's in the HTML tag.

Why does this happen? How to fix?

EXAMPLE?

```
Property 'h11' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.ts(2339)

export default function App() {
    return <h11>Hello World</h11>;
}


$ eslint "src/**/*.ts?(x)"
Done in 2.98s.
```

Answer (score 0):

`h11` isn't a HTML tag, they go from `h1` to `h6`. It's warning you that h11 isn't in the list of natural HTML tags.

To fix:

```js
export default function App() {
    return <h1>Hello World</h1>;
}
```

Comment: This is obvious. The question is, why didn't ESLINT catch this syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

In /.vscode/settings.json

```
{
  "eslint.validate": [ "javascript", "html" ]
}
```

In .eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "plugins": [
    "eslint-plugin-html",
  ],
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "rules": {
  }
};
```

Comment: How do you configure it to work within .ts and .tsx extensions?